Does the fixed point set of an isometry have measure zero?
Suppose $M$ is a connected Riemannian manifold and $f:M\to M$ is an isometry. $f\neq \mathrm{Id}$. $F = \{p\in M\mid f(p) = p\}$ is the fixed point set of $f$. Does $F$ have measure zero?
I can only prove that $M\backslash F$ is dense in $M$. In fact, if it is not dense, then $\mathrm{Int}(F) = (\overline{M\backslash F})^{c}$ is a nonempty open subset of $M$. Then there exists a point $p\in \mathrm{Int}(F)$ such that $f(p) = p$ and $df_{p} = \mathrm{Id}$. Since $M$ is connected and $f$ is an isometry, we deduce that $f = \mathrm{Id}$, a contradiction.
But it seems that $M\backslash F$ being dense is not in general imply that $F$ has measure zero.

But isn’t $F$ a submanifold?
